# Shinobi Chsrts grid lines custom number of lines

Tags: objective-c, shinobi

I try to create grid lines for my chart using Shinobi Charts,
I can see that the amount of lines for axis depended of amount of ticks  that displayed for the axis.

I'm using this code to define grid lines:

```
axis.majorTickFrequency = @(3);
for (SChartAxis *axis in mainChart.allAxes)
{

    axis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = YES;
    axis.style.majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = @(0.5);
    axis.style.majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = APP_GRAY_COLOR;
}
```

Is there a way to set wanted amount of grid lines?

Answer (score 0):

Tick marks and grid-lines are intrinsically linked, so it's not possible to specify independent scales.

However, there is a delegate method on `SChartDelegate` which allows you to have ultimate control over the tick marks (and hence the grid lines):

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark
                                beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis
```

This method provides you with a `SChartTickMark` object from which you could remove the `gridLineView` should you want to.